# define $HOME variable in gnome-terminal profile (for bash)

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

How do I do this. I've tried setting this in a script and in the "command" to run at launch in gnome-terminal profile preferences.

Additionally, there is a full set of .bashrc .*rc files in the new $HOME location that I _do_not_ want bash to use as at terminal startup ... maybe this is part of the problem. There may not be way to do this?

Comment: first of all: _why_ do you want to change the value of HOME? do you simply want to change the home directory of your user?

Comment: I do work on a server with everything nicely setup in /home/user/ but the server is slow so it's would be nice to do some development on the local box as if I was working on the server. Superficially, I thought redefining $HOME might be a good way of doing this ... anyway, it's probably a bad idea altogether. I think bad things can happen redefining HOME since so many processes may depend onit.

Comment: you could move your home directory with `usermod -d /new/path -m` the `-m` option ensures that all the content is moved to the new directory. you need superuseraccess to do this change though. and always make a backup of your files before doing such stuff.